# How to custom sort a multidimensional list with given label in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

How do I custom sort a multidimensional list in the order I want ? (without using any external modules or libraries)

For example, I have a multidimensional list:

```
[['M', 'A', 'R', 'K']
[1,    3,   5,    4]
[2,    6,   7,    8]]
```

I want to sort its columns into R, K, A, M order like:

```
[['R', 'K', 'A', 'M']
[5,    4,   3,    1]
[7,    8,   6,    2]]
```

I only know how to sort a list alphabetically according using this code:

```
sorted_l = [i for i in zip(*sorted(zip(*l)))]
```

which generates the following result:

```
[['A', 'K', 'M', 'R']
[3,    4,   1,    5]
[6,    8,   2,    7]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What criteria is used for ordering to get this order `['R', 'K', 'A', 'M']`?

Comment: @Marcin I will have a string user input that I can custom sort the columns of this multidimensional list the way I want. For example string = RKAM; string = AKRM; string = RKAM whatever order I want.

Comment: @falsetru No, I want it to be sorted by columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l= [['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'],[1,    3,   5,    4],[2,    6,   7,    8]]
inds = "RKAM"

print(sorted(zip(*l),key=lambda x: inds.index(x[0])))
[('R', 5, 7), ('K', 4, 8), ('A', 3, 6), ('M', 1, 2)]

print(zip(*sorted(zip(*l),key=lambda x: inds.index(x[0]))))

[('R', 'K', 'A', 'M'), (5, 4, 3, 1), (7, 8, 6, 2)]In [6]: trans = 

In [6]: trans = sorted(zip(*l),key=lambda x: inds.index(x[0]))    
In [7]: trans[0] # each 0 in  inds.index(x[0]) is either R,K, A or M
Out[7]: ('R', 5, 7)
In [8]: trans[1]
Out[8]: ('K', 4, 8)
In [9]: trans[2]
Out[9]: ('A', 3, 6)    
In [10]: trans[3]
Out[10]: ('M', 1, 2)

In [11]: zip(*trans) # finally transpose sorted columns again
Out[11]: [('R', 'K', 'A', 'M'), (5, 4, 3, 1), (7, 8, 6, 2)]
```

Comment: @MarlonC.Carrillo, we transpose first and sort the columns by the first element in each column based on their index/position in our inds string, the outer zip just transposes the list again. If `['M', 'A', 'R', 'K']` was in the second row you could use `inds.index(x[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = [['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'],
...      [1,    3,   5,    4],
...      [2,    6,   7,    8]]
>>> indexes = [2, 3, 1, 0]
>>> [[row[i] for i in indexes] for row in l]
[['R', 'K', 'A', 'M'],
 [5, 4, 3, 1],
 [7, 8, 6, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way using ittemgetter

```
l = [['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'],
    [1,    3,   5,    4],
    [2,    6,   7,    8]]       

from operator import itemgetter    

itg = itemgetter(2, 3, 1, 0)   
print([itg(row) for row in l])
```

Gives:

```
   [('R', 'K', 'A', 'M'), (5, 4, 3, 1), (7, 8, 6, 2)]
```

the samae `itg` can also be constructed using the new "header" order, e.g.

```
a_string = "RKAM"
itg = itemgetter(*[l[0].index(v) for v in a_string])
```

Comment: I think the whole point is being able to use the letters to index the array

Comment: Maybe, its not really clear how the OP wants to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose it, make it into a `dict`, find the columns then transpose back

```
>>> L = [['M', 'A', 'R', 'K'],
[1,    3,   5,    4],
[2,    6,   7,    8]]
>>> cols = dict((x[0], x) for x in zip(*L))
>>> zip(*[cols[k] for k in ('R', 'K', 'A', 'M')])
[('R', 'K', 'A', 'M'), (5, 4, 3, 1), (7, 8, 6, 2)]
```